# Remove a file in all commits before a certain date

Tags: git

How to delete a file for all commits is already answered, but I have problems to specify a range for the commits I want to modify. I want to delete `MYFILE` from all commits before 2017-12-13.

This is the way I tried to do it.

`git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch MYFILE' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --before="2017-12-13"`

Answer (score 1):

`--` separates options from non-option arguments. In your case it's not needed so the command should be

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch MYFILE' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat --before="2017-12-13"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. When I run the line of code, the terminal shows me the options of git filter-branch.

I ran it without the cat command in the end, too, but then the file got removed from all the commits...

Comment: Then it seems the task is impossible — probably because `filter-branch` must rewrite the entire branch up to its head. Use `rebase` — it also rewrites the entire branch but you can edit only those commits you're interested.